# How do I identify the clicked element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an Element overlay, that has some functionality when clicked anywhere inside that area:

```
<div id="overlay">
    some html and some <a href="#">links</a>
</div>
```

Now I would like something else to happen only, if you clicked on a link inside that area:

```
$('#overlay').click(function() {
if(clicked_element=="a") alert("clicked inside");
    else alert("you clicked a link");
});
```

How can I complete this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$('#overlay').click(function(e) { // <- note the parameter
   alert(e.target); // <- the target
});
```

In your example, it would be something like:

```
$('#overlay').click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.nodeName == "A"){ 
        alert("clicked inside");
    }else{
         alert("you clicked a link");
    }
});
```

For completeness, here is a native JavaScript solution:

```
document.getElementById("#overlay").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    alert(e.target);
},false);
```

If you want to find the *closest* `<a>` to the target you can use [jQuery's `closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: but target is not set, if not clicked on a link

Comment: ah ok, I first thought "target" would be the target of the `a href` but its the target of the mouse, that is clicked. Thanks, that works!

Comment: @rubo77 For completeness, the `href` value is stored inside `e.target.href` if the user clicked on the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#overlay').on('click', 'a', function() {
   //'this' now refers to clicked link
});
```

Comment: and how do I refer to clicked on a not-link?

Comment: Ahh ok, misread the question i think. If you are targeting specific elements then the 2nd parameter is just a jQuery selector

Answer (score 0):

First get the `event` object: `.click(function(e) {`

Then its `target` property (`e.target)` will be the element you clicked. To be sure you get the link, try this:

```
var target = e.target;
while(target && target.nodeName != "A") target = target.parentNode;
```

This will be useful for example if you have an image in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#overlay').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'A') {
        alert("Link clicked");
    } else {
        alert('overlay clicked');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7jJDu/2/)

Comment: What if the user clicked on something _inside_ a link (for example an image in a link)? This would still alert 'link clicked' unlike in OP's example since the clicked element is _not_ the a but the image.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this, I have updated the code to over come this issue.